# Exec command not feeding back output

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When executing the command found in the `importCommand` variable in terminal, the command correctly feeds back output and begins the import.

When executed in Node, the application hangs and I receive no output (I'm not sure if it's doing anything).

The `firebase-import` extension can be found here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import

Could anyone please tell me why the script isn't feeding back info/executing the command as it should?

```
const importCommand = 'firebase-import --database_url mydatabase.com --path /path --json ./file.json --force --service_account ./service.json';

const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const child = exec(importCommand,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but changing the code to the following worked:

```
const importCommand = 'firebase-import --database_url mydatabase.com --path /path --json ./file.json --force --service_account ./service.json';
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const importProcess = exec(importCommand);

importProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

importProcess.stdout.on('exit', () => {
  console.log('Finished importing stops');
});
```